# Can't import google plus plugin in ionic 3 project 's module

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-plus

I'm developing `Hybrid` app using `ionic-3`. I'm getting trouble to import google plus plugin in app.module.ts and page.ts.
I have successfully installed google plus plugin from below command but first time i'm facing this issue.

> $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid
>
> $ npm install --save @ionic-native/google-plus

My import error is in below images

> App.module.ts

[image]

> Page.ts

[image]

> Ionic Info

cli packages: (C:\Users\sandip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.1.4
npm  : 6.5.0
OS   : Windows 8
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : E:\newsdk\newsdk\tools;E:\newsdk\newsdk\platform-tools;E:\newsdk\newsdk\build-tools
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

I hope this information is enough to understand my issue.

Comment: There is no provider class with 'googleplusoriginal'. it should be 'googleplus'. check is there any googleplusoriginal type is getting used in your project code base.

Comment: i have checked there is not any googleplusoriginal type is getting used.

Comment: If you don't have any 'googleplusoriginal ' type in codebase. How VSCode is reporting issue. try deleting 'node_modules' folder, execute 'npm install'

Answer (score 3):

Try to import this in the module that you are working:

```
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx'

@ngModule({
   ...
   providers: [
      ...
      GooglePlus
    ]
})
```

Comment: notice the `/ngx` at the end. If you miss it, you will get wierd errors.